# What is the right way to manually interact with contracts in Ganache?

Tags: truffle, ganache

I've deployed and properly configured MetaCoin with Truffle and Ganache. But I don't see a way to actually interact with the deployed contract via Ganache's UI?
https://trufflesuite.com/docs/ganache/workspaces/ethereum-workspace-overview

I'm looking for something akin to truffle's `truffle develop` command but on the ganache ui but it doesn't seem like it's possible? It would be nice if using `truffle develop` would update the ganache ui but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
truffle(develop)> let result = await instance.sendCoin(accounts[1], 50, {from: accounts[0]})
undefined
truffle(develop)> result
{
  tx: '0xfd02d837ab771ef3f13e9d3ce8fa02e4e9159d7dcf3335b9b49ead208dc6c7ee',
  receipt: {
    transactionHash: '0xfd02d837ab771ef3f13e9d3ce8fa02e4e9159d7dcf3335b9b49ead208dc6c7ee',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    blockNumber: 2,
    blockHash: '0x73d62b01fab09cef590c51ddb75a7160d78118bbece1ed7aad3b9654ee396680',
    to: '0x48ed36fc12efd57c74c5fb027278a4b9b38fdfef',
    cumulativeGasUsed: 21572,
    gasUsed: 21572,
    contractAddress: null,
    logs: [],
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    status: true,
    effectiveGasPrice: '0xc2b031e0',
    type: '0x2',
    rawLogs: []
  },
  logs: []
}
```